# how to check whether a string can fit into richtextbox visible area

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to divide a very large string into slices so that each slice can fit into the visible area of a richtextbox so that the horizontal scroll bar will not show.

I would like to know how to determine whether a string can fit into the richtextbox's visible area without changing the richtextbox's value.

I searched for the solution and most results I found suggest that MeasureText / MeasureString should be used, but it seems these two function assume there is only one line(not wrapped).

Is there any way to find out the height of a multiple line string which will be set into a richtextbox?

Comment: why vote close?

Comment: With WordWrap set to true, you shouldn't see a Horizontal Scroll bar.

Comment: @LarsTech we cannot control the vertical scroll bar, right?

Comment: What's there to control?

Comment: @LarsTech to force it invisible. Because in my case, if the string is longer enough, it will cause the wrapper string extend outside the visible area of richtextbox. Then the vscroll bar will turn on automatically

Comment: `richTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;`

Comment: @LarsTech In this case, part of the string is beyond the visible area. I would like to show all the string without trigger the scroll bar. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeasureText` and `MeasureString` functions has **overloads** that accept `textarea width, height` and `TextFormatFlags(TextBoxControl, WordBreak e.t.c)`

You can compare your `text size` with `RichTextBoxControl size`

```
Size stringSize = new Size();
string text = SomeText();
stringSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, richTextBox1.Font, new Size(richTextBox1.Size.Width, richTextBox1.Size.Height), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
string r = string.Format("RTB Width : {0}\r\n", richTextBox1.Size.Width);
r += string.Format("RTB Height : {0}\r\n", richTextBox1.Size.Height);
r += string.Format("TEXT Width : {0}\r\n", stringSize.Width);
r += string.Format("TEXT Height : {0}", stringSize.Height);
MessageBox.Show(r);
```